# WARNING: No mapping for springapp1 welcome.htm in DispatcherServlet with name springapp1

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I have created a simple jsp page which is being retrieved by the controller. But when I retreive this url localhost:8080/springapp1/welcome.htm, I am getting the following error in tomcat:

I am getting this error:

```
WARNING: No mapping for [/springapp1/welcome.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp1'
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >
<servlet>
<servlet-name>springapp1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springapp1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp1-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

springapp1.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<!-- the application context definition for the springapp1 DispatcherServlet -->

<context:component-scan base-package="springapp1.web" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

HelloWorldController.java:

```
package springapp1.web;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController{

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

    logger.info("returning hello view with ");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("userForm");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
}
}
```

userForm.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring MVC Hello World Annotation Example</h1>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are deploying your application into root context (i.e. `/`)? In that case your URL should be `http://localhost:8080/welcome.htm`.

Comment: I missed the http tag in my question. I am using it but to no avail. Is there a way I can send/upload my project files? Please help.